# Not able to make Redshift connection in AWS glue, where the redshift is located in different location (us-west-1)

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

Redshift is located in Us-west - 1 region and aws glue is not supported in us-west-1 region. so i have created aws glue in different region and trying to access the redshift. When am adding the connection in AWS glue, not getting the redshift cluster detail in drop down. So i tried with jdbc connection, but is failing.What should i have to make for successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Redshift connection will appear on the dropdown only if you are trying to make conection to redshift cluster in that account. for every other redshift cluster (which is in any region / any account), you need to use JDBC, it should work fine, unless you haven't provided the connection enough info.
Anyway if you can post the error, that would be helpful to resolve to the point.
some common things to check for:

***1. check Reddhsift Security Group (if it is allowing only connections
    from particular ip cidr).***

***2. Check if your target RedshiftCluster is SSL
        enabled and if it is, make sure you are giving the ssl validation
        thing also at end of your host URL.***